# Use erigon to retrieve all transactions for a specific address

Tags: web3js, rust, erigon

Is it possible to use erigon to retrieve all transactions issued or received by a particular address at once?
If so, I would like to know how to do it, for example, using the javacript library (web3.js...), rust crate (Web3 crate), or using the curl command.

Thank you in advance.